# JSF JSTL Functions

Tags: jstl, jsf-2.2

I use JSF Mojarra 2.2.9 in combination with the JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL) 1.2.1.
The files javax.faces-2.2.9.jar and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar I imported in the libs folder in WEB-INF.
But I can't use its functions.

When I load this facelet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
...
<composite:implementation>
Name: #{fn:replace(cc.clientId, '-', '')}
</composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Function 'fn:replace' not found
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:209)
    at org.apache.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.flushTextBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.addInstruction(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.endTag(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.popTag(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1783)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2970)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(Unknown Source)
    ... 107 more
```

My Maven dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <!-- Apache Tomcat -->
    <tomcat.version>8.0.22</tomcat.version>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <!-- JSF Mojarra -->
    <jsf.version>2.2.9</jsf.version>
    <!-- JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL) -->
    <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
    <!-- Expression Language API -->
    <el.api.version>2.2</el.api.version>
    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <primefaces.version>5.3</primefaces.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>${el.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs with JSTL functions in JSF 2.2.

One bug, is the one you are having. And that JSF will not fix now or in the future. So that is now a feature.

The second one is the one I am having, for which the following sample application was created:
https://github.com/99sono/jsf-2-2-fn-replace-not-found-bug/blob/master/README.md

In the case of your bug the explanation can be found in:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3469

The problem you are having is that according to the comments on the glassfish, jira, you are not allowed to use INLINE fn:replace functions in composite components, which are complex enough as it is.

Please try to work-around your issue by encapsulating the fn:replace function in the "value" attirbute of an .

And I quote Manfred Riem:

> While I understand that inline EL is a nice convenience as you already
>   have found out it is problematic with respect to composite components.
>   When you are using composite components please replace # {xx} with
>    and everything will work as you expect.
>   A little background to the problem the SAXCompiler (the internal
>   Facelets class that converts the markup does not convert inline EL to